# 3D Line from polar to parametric

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

I have a line in 3D space that passes through the origin and is defined by two angles, $\theta$, and $\phi$.
How do I find a parametric equation for this line?

For Example:
if $\theta = \pi / 4$ and $\phi = \pi / 4$
then I think the parametric equations would be
$x = t$, $y = t$, and $z = t$ (Where $t$ is the parameter)
Of course, I could be wrong, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Are the angles spherical coordinates?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of such a line? Or is part of the difficulty that you don't know _any_ way to describe the line using these angles as coordinates? (If you don't, the "from" in the title is inaccurate--to convert the definition of a line from something to anything else you must first have the "something" you want to convert from.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (x,y,z) = r (\cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi \sin \theta ,\sin \phi) $$

is a Cartesian parametric equation of a radial line through origin of variable radius length $r.$

Please note that spherical coordinates or parameters $\theta, \phi $ are given or fixed but $r$ varies.